# Loading Module Uncaught ReferenceError: SystemJS is not defined

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I need to load a module and can't seem to resolve this error even though it is prevalent on the web and I have attempted some of the solutions:

I have a class like this:

```
export class Example{
    public Name: string;
    public Id: number;   
}
```

Import the class into the app.js file:

```
import { Example } from "./exampleClass";

let example = new Example();

example.Name = "Hello World";

document.write(example.Name);
```

Tried this:

First in the tsconfig:

```
"module": "system"

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <script>
     SystemJS.config({
         baseURL: '/',
         defaultJSExtensions: true
     });
     SystemJS.import('./dist/app.js');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this:

```
    <script>
     SystemJS.config({
         baseURL: '/',
         packages: {

            '/': {
                defaultJSExtensions: 'js'
            }
         }
     });
     SystemJS.import('./dist/app.js');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method "System.import()" instead of the method "SystemJS.config()". For example see the HTML file, "index.html" file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Learning TypeScript</title>
        <script src='node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">Change it with jQuery</div>
        <script>
            System.import('./app.js');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Be sure that in your "package.json" file there is the following code, 'cause you're using SystemJS as module loader:

```
"dependencies": {
  "systemjs": "^6.1.2"
},
```

Be sure that in your TypeScript configuration file, "tsconfig.json" file, there is the following code, 'cause you're using SystemJS as module loader:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
```

Comment: I get this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to resolve specifier app.js`

Comment: Try with System.import('./dist/app.js'); instead of System.import('./app.js');